# how to convert lists in string in numpy array to a numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have this numpy array ['[-30,30]' '[-30,30]' '[-30,30]' '[-30,30]']
But I would like to convert it into [[-30,30] [-30,30] [-30,30] [-30,30]]

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the input? Certainly not a numpy array. Here you have a single string embedded in a list

Comment: Input is ['[-30,30]' '[-30,30]' '[-30,30]' '[-30,30]'] ,it is a numpy array consist of strings and output should look like [[-30,30] [-30,30] [-30,30] [-30,30]] just a numpy array

Comment: So input is `['[-30,30][-30,30][-30,30][-30,30]']`? `'a' 'b'` in python is `'ab'`

Comment: That's the same, run it in a python shell. Thus my question, your input is unclear. Do you then mean `"['[-30,30]' '[-30,30]' '[-30,30]' '[-30,30]']"`? Or `['[-30,30]', '[-30,30]', '[-30,30]', '[-30,30]']`?

Comment: this is the input ['[-30,30]' '[-30,30]' '[-30,30]' '[-30,30]']

Comment: It seems likely you are missing comma's in between entries...

Comment: No there is no comma between them , they arraz numpy array and its elements are in strings. It is not list

Comment: let's phrase it in another way, can you complete this `x = ...` so that if I run this in my python shell and then type `x` I get the desired object?

Comment: x=np.array(['[-30,30]','[-30,30]','[-30,30]', '[-30,30]']) this is x and x is an input and y should be output without any string, just nested array [[-30,30] [-30,30] [-30,30] [-30,30]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) like below:

```
>>> import ast
>>> lst = np.array(['[-30,30]','[-30,30]','[-30,30]', '[-30,30]'])

>>> type(lst[0])
numpy.str_

>>> type(ast.literal_eval(lst[0]))
list

>>> np.array(list(map(ast.literal_eval, lst)))
array([[-30,  30],
       [-30,  30],
       [-30,  30],
       [-30,  30]])
```